# Call all test script with test function(based on tester choice) into main Test script file in JUnit

Tags: selenium, junit, webdriver

System Information:
OS: Win XP (32bit)
Selenium Webdriver: 3.32
Firefox: 20.0
Junit: 4.0
Eclipse: 3.8

I have two test script file over JUnit(4.0) under my test project. These files are working fine.

I have an issue that I want to make a main script file which call my all test script file in to it.
1.**GooglePageTest.java** have 5 test functions which is running as expected.

2.**TestGoogleApp.java** have 8 test functions which is running as expected.

3.Now I have one main script file(**MainTest.java**) which call some of the function form GooglePageTest and TestGoogleApp.
Please provide me the solution how I can do this. I tried to put some code over MainTest.java file, 
please see the below code for your reference:

```
import org.junit.Before;
public class MainTest 
{
public GoogalePageTest test;
public TestGoogleApp test2;
 @Before
 public void setUP()
 {
  test  = new GoogalePageTest();
  test2 = new TestGoogleApp();
 }
 //@Test
 public void test()
 {
  try{
       // This line call all the test function from the GooglPageTest file, 
       // rather than one function.
       test.Googletest01();   //Run only this test function
       //test.Googletest02(); //Do not run this test function

       //Run this test only from the test script TestGoogleApp
       test2.WebTest02();
      }catch(Exception e)
        {
     e.printStackTrace();
     System.out.println(" Error description: " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

But when I am trying to run this code then it call all test function from the GoogalePageTest file.

Can you help me in this how I can solve this issue.

Any help or suggestion is appreciable.

You can drop me your suggestion here or mail me with your suggestion or  question/concern against this at niraj06.srivastava@gmail.com

Thanks in advance

Regards 
Neeraj S